# Eclipse - Does it have a method drop down like XCode?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, flash-builder

Does Eclipse have a method drop down like XCode? Or is there a plugin to add one?

Comment: What exactly in Xcode you mean with drop down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse has *quick outline* via <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> which shows methods and attributes of a class.

[image: quick-outline]

Comment: Ôn Windows it is Control - o